# R Workspace History

Tags: r

Is it possible to view the history of a loaded workspace? I wasn't aware that you have to save a separate history file and I am not working on the same machine as I was when I made the original .RData file. When I use history() none of the previous workspace commands appear.

For example say in the original workspace I have a command
    y <- x+z

After loading the workspace I can use y but I can't see the command that created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately , ... "No". The history mechanism is separate from the `save.image` process. They use different file destinations and there is no recording of the code with the .RData files.